# Using CompositeInputFormat - Map-side Join

Tags: java, hadoop, input, mapreduce

I am triyng to execute a Map-side Join using CompositeInputFormat. The mapper function is not even called. Below are the two files.

FILE A - KEY#VALUE

```
1#1;1
1#1;2
1#1;3
1#1;5
2#2;2
2#2;2
3#3;2
3#3;3
5#5;2
5#5;2
```

FILE B - KEY#VALUE

```
1#1;1
1#1;1
1#1;1
1#1;1
```

SourceCode

```
Path left= new Path(args[0]);
Path rigth = new Path(args[1])
String separator = "#";
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", separator);
String joinExpression = CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner",   KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, left, rigth);
config.set("mapreduce.join.expr", joinExpression);

Job job =  Job.getInstance(config);
job.setJobName("Blah");
job.setJarByClass(Blah.class);
job.setMapperClass(PreditorasMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(PreditorasReducer.class);
job.setInputFormatClass(CompositeInputFormat.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the mapper class.

I was using:

```
public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
```

instead of:

```
public void map(Text key, TupleWritable value, Context context)
```